# CarrierWave fails to render picture in Rails 3.1 production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, carrierwave

For some reason, the picture that I upload using carrierwave is not showing up on the app. This only happens when I try to deploy the app in production. I configured my store directory to be like this:

```
def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

And in my html source file, I see that it is accessing the image from

```
/uploads/picture/image/1/thumb_mango.jpg
```

However, I see that the picture is missing when it is on PRODUCTION. In development, it is rendering the picture just fine. The picture is stored inside the 'public' folder. So the path would be like:

```
/public/uploads/...
```

Comment: What is your hosting environment? It might be a heroku tmp directory issue. Check out the answer here regarding your config settings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368554/howto-basic-setup-of-carrierwave-heroku-and-s3

Comment: Did you solve that?! I have exactly same problem with Rails 3.2 on my VPS!

Comment: I ended up using RackSpace cloud files for those =)

Comment: Whats the solution for this ?
Me too facing exactly same issue hosting on softlayer.