# howto: Basic setup of carrierwave [Heroku and S3]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

I have an S3 bucket for production and development. I have done my research and [came across this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506028/carrierwave-fog-argument-error-provider-not-recognized) but my current config does not work as expected. I get the following exception (below) locally and I get no file uploads to my S3 bucket from my heroku app:

```
 is not a recognized storage provider
 Extracted source (around line #3):

 1: 
 2: <p><%= user.name %></p>
 3: <%= image_tag user.avatar.url %>
 4: <%= link_to 'Show', user %>
 5: <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %>
 6: <%= link_to 'Destroy', user, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
```

**However** When I set `storage :file` inside of the `*_uploader.rb` file everything works as expected locally. But still noting ever gets sent to my S3 bucket.

Here is my set up:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remote_avatar_url, :remove_avatar
 mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

**fog.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.production?
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider              => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_K'],
    :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SCRT'],
    :region                => ENV['S3_RG']
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  config.fog_host       = 'http://www.example.com' 
  config.fog_public     = true                                    # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}

else
 #for development and testing locally
  config.storage = :file
  config.enable_processing = false
 end
end
```

***_uploader.rb**

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

 storage :fog

 def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
 end

 def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
 end

 end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def new
 @user = User.new
 @user.avatar = params[:file]
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # new.html.erb
   format.json { render json: @user }
  end
end

def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
 @user.avatar = params[:file]
  respond_to do |format|
   if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
   else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
end
```

end

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @CanBerkGüder I can confirm that I am able to save the record but not the image file. Anytime I attempt to create a user object, my heroku log spits out:

```
2012-02-20T23:19:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:46:in `block in create'
2012-02-20T23:19:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:45:in `create'
2012-02-20T23:19:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-20T23:19:45+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /users] invalidate, pass
```

Comment: Two things to check: 1. is the 'fog' gem listed in your Gemfile? 2. if it is, try specifying config.storage = :fog in the initializer.

Comment: @CanBerkGüder I updated my initializer and still no luck, please see the UPDATE section for what happened after I updated.

Comment: The directory structure is not important, as the docs say, simply because there are no directories on S3 (it's just a file named uploads/user/avatar/1/2_48x48.png). Unfortunately, I can't think of a third reason that might cause the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's an idea. CarrierWave still includes an S3 adapter for backward compatibility that uses fog underneath, which I personally use instead of `:fog`. In theory, there should be no difference between the two, but I think it's worth a shot. Here's my CarrierWave initializer from a live application running on Heroku:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  if Rails.env.production?
    config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp')
    config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave'

    config.storage = :s3
    config.s3_access_key_id = ENV['S3_KEY']
    config.s3_secret_access_key = ENV['S3_SECRET']
    config.s3_bucket = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  else
    config.storage = :file
  end
end
```

The first two lines (config.root and config.cache_dir) are there to work around Heroku's read-only filesystem, which *should* have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I came across the two line update in the docs, thanks for reminding me. What should my controller look like? Do I have to add a line like `@user.avatar = params[:file]` to in my `new` and `create` actions?

Comment: Your answer did not work in my setup, but it definitely inspired some research on my part! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One issue might be

```
config.fog_host       = 'http://www.example.com'
```

If you use this setting, you probably need a real host there. Supposedly you can comment that line out, although I've seen it highly recommended.

And I assume you set your ENV variables on Heroku?

```
heroku config:add S3_K=[my_s3_key] S3_SCRT=[my_s3_secret] S3_RG=[us-east-1]S3_BUCKET=[my_bucket_name]
```

I used pretty much the same setup. Mine didn't work, but I think I got a step or two further:

```
Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
```